# Unable load files within library in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, phpmailer

I've written a function within Controller to use PHPMailer and it works fine. After that I need this Function frequently and eventually I decide to write Library. But when do this and load Library within Controller, It has error like this :

> Message: Call to undefined method PHPMailerOAuth::isSMTP()

After all I've figured out there is problem with path! I've tried what ever you're thinking but it doesn't work!
I've tried Controller as library
I've tried `include()`,`require_once()`,`require`, with or without `APPATH`.
I've search as much as I could. Even I've read about `Third Party` but I don't understand.
Is there any idea to load PHPMailer file within Library?
Thank you in advance.

It's library called PHPMailer.php

```
class PHPMailer {

public function singleMail($setFromTitle,$setToMail,$setToName,$setSubject,$setMessage)
{
    date_default_timezone_set('Etc/UTC');
    require 'vendor/phpmailer/phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';
    require 'vendor/autoload.php';
    $mail = new PHPMailerOAuth;
    $mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
    $mail->isSMTP();
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 2;
    $mail->Debugoutput = 'html';
    $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
    $mail->Port = 587;
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
    $mail->AuthType = 'XOAUTH2';
    $mail->oauthUserEmail = "XXX@gmail.com";
    $mail->oauthClientId = "XXX";
    $mail->oauthClientSecret = "XXX";
    $mail->oauthRefreshToken = "XXX";
    $mail->setFrom('XXXy@zounkan.com', $setFromTitle);
    $mail->addAddress($setToMail, $setToName);
    $mail->Subject = $setSubject;
    $mail->msgHTML($setMessage);
    if (!$mail->send()) {
        echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    } else {
        echo "Message sent!";
    }
}
```

And it's how I load this library within Controller's function :

```
$this->load->library('PHPMailer');
$this->phpmailer->singleMail($setFromTitle,$setToMail,$setToName,$setSubject,$setMessage);
```

Comment: Show us your code.

Comment: It's all that I have.

Comment: did you try using the require out side of the class ?

Comment: I know what's Phpmailer, but you are not showing your whole code. I don't see `PHPMailerOAuth` class anywhere.

Comment: Problem is not with path, problem is that class `PHPMailerOAuth` has no method `isSMTP`. Just `PHPMailer` class has this method.

Comment: So what you need is `$mail = new PHPMailer;`

Comment: No - `PHPMailerOAuth` is a subclass of `PHPMailer`, so it inherits `isSMTP()`. I'm surprised you need to load composer's autoloader at this point - don't you load it globally? If you're loading PHPMailer with composer, you don't need to load PHPMailer's own autoloader as well - one is enough. While I'm, here, I suggest looking at the PHPMailer 6.0 branch - the OAuth support is much better.

Comment: @u_mulder Thank you for your answer but my PHPMailer as I said it works fine and this is what exactly PHPMailer displayed as Example.

Comment: @Synchro Thank you too. I have shared host and I manually upload vendor folder in this path (https://example.com/phpmailer/vendor/rest_of_phpmailer_dependencies). I've called it from root path but I have same error!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to PHPMailer's owner, he helped me and eventually solve this problem!
It should happen for every programmer and when I fixed it I surprised! The problem was about the class name! I define PHPMailer class as Library's class and it's not allowed! So intead of code above (That I'v mentioned) I should try this and it works fine as well :

```
class Sendingmail {
     public function singleMail($setFromTitle,$setToMail,$setToName,$setSubject,$setMessage) {
          // Rest of codes
     }
}
```

So don't named your class to PHPMailer or something like this which probably has defined in core functions!